# Prove $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty }\mu (\left \{ |f|>n \right \})=0$

Tags: general-topology, analysis, measure-theory

given: $(X,A,\mu )$ measure space and $\mu (X)<\infty $ and $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ measurable function

my work: let $B_{n}=\left \{ |f|>n \right \}=|f|^{-1}(]n,+\infty [)$

then $B_{n}=X-|f|^{-1}(]-\infty ,n])$

as $n\rightarrow \infty $,$B_{n}\rightarrow X-|f|^{-1}(]-\infty ,+\infty [)=X-X=\varnothing $

$\mu (B_{n})\rightarrow \mu (\varnothing )=0$

Is what I did correct ?

Comment: it is correct, yes

Comment: ok, I have few questions, in the last step I assumed the a measure is continuous, is it always continuous ? (a measure), and also in the given, $f$ is measurable, I didn't use this

Comment: The measurabilty of $f$ guarantees that the sets $B_n$ are measurable so that $\mu(B_n)$ is well defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting $A_n=B_{n}-B_{n+1}$ for $n=1,2,\dots$ we find that $$B_k=\bigcup_{n=k}^{\infty}A_n\text{ for every }k$$where the $A_n$ are measurable and disjoint.

Then for every $k$:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\mu(A_n)+\mu(B_k)=\mu(B_1)<\infty$$Taking the limit for $k\to\infty$ we find:$$\mu(B_1)+\lim_{k\to\infty}\mu(B_k)=\mu(B_1)$$This assures that: $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\mu(B_k)=0$$